# Magento configurable products got updated only after saving them manually

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.8

In magento 1.8 the configurable products are not updated of the sample products, for example if one of the sample products is out of stock it shouldn't appear in the front end as an option of the configurable product, So I have to go to admin panel and save this configurable product manually, then it got updated or refreshed and the option of this sample product disappeared. I have tried to reindex and clear the caches but it didn't work, only saving the product works, and it is a very hard work to go to each product open and save it.

Is there any suggestion?

Comment: Do you have any module installed

Comment: I have many modules installed.. which module you mean?